# Where should I place a feature request for a specific site?

Tags: discussion, support

Last December I had a feature request for the Travel SE site. The feature request is only for this site, because on other site it wouldn't been that necessary.

Therefore I asked a [question on the meta site of Travel SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/491/693) and tagged it with feature-request. However, no Stackexchange representative seems to have looked at it since then. So where should I place an official feature request for a specific site?

Comment: If they do not respond it does not necessarily mean that they did not see it.  SE gets mountains of feature requests - not all can be dealt with personally.

Comment: How do you know they haven't looked at it?

Comment: @TheEstablishment I don't know that, but if they looked at it I would have expected a short comment or a new tag.

Answer (score 10):

You've posted it in the right place - on the meta for the site in question.

Unfortunately you can't really check whether any one from Stack Exchange has actually looked at something if they don't post a comment, answer or add a [status_*] flag. We are assured that Stack Exchange employees do check the site metas regularly.

If you think the question hasn't had enough attention you could raise the issue in your chat for a one of your site moderators to escalate the issue to Stack Exchange.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Jin, for example, has a [tag filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters) for [meta-tag:design] across the meta-network. I don't know if this is true for other employees, but starting with proper tagging is probably also an important step in getting the request seen.

Comment: "We are *assured*"...

Comment: @casperOne - have you got a problem with my correct use of English?

Comment: No...  Emphasis on the choice of words.  Directed at SE, not you.